# How to specify where to place bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

How do I specify where I want my bibliography placed?

I need it to be placed before the appendices and to appear in the table of contents.

If it's relevant I'm using TeXnicCenter with MiKTeX and BibTeX. The document class is `report`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use several possible methods for bibliography:

**Embedded system**:

`thebibliography` environment is positioned where it placed in the source code.

**Old-style `bibtex` + [`natbib`](ftp://sunsite.icm.edu.pl/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf)**:

Bibliography placed where the `\bibliography{}` command is presented.

**Modern style - [`biblatex`](ftp://sunsite.icm.edu.pl/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)**:

`\printbibliography` defines the position of bibliography.

Answer (score 4):

The standard method is like this, for the `report` class; adjust for your class.

```
\documentclass{report}

< other packages >

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % <-- this will make the bib appear in the TOC

<customization part>

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

<material>

\bibliographystyle{whatever}
\bibliography{yourbibfile}

\appendix
<appendix material>

\end{document}
```

Of course this is only a scheme.

Comment: I forgot to mention in the question that I also needed the ToC entry to be numbered and this answer lead me to read the `tocbibind` documentation which showed how to do that: `\usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind}`